# creating zip/rar/tar of folders in Joomla

Tags: php, zip, gzip, joomla1.5, tar

Please somebody help me.
I want to **compress a folder** (which contains images & text files as well as few sub folders) **in zip,rar,tar format** & then give it for download to user.
Is there any class/api/library/code to do so.

I am working on Joomla CMS.

Regards,

Shahu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Joomla has compression and decompression in it's API.

See the documentation on JArchive:

The updated link to docs: 
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JArchiveTar.html